# performing intersections between lists of numbers in vba

Tags: vba

I'm new with vba (i know only R) and I'd need to perform the operation below but i don't know how to do it:

I need to create two distinct lists of numbers, for example: A={2,4,6,8,9} and B={4,6,9} and then I need to create a third variable that contains only the numbers of A that **are not** in B: C={2,8}.
How can i do that?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

VBA does not provide a method or structure for doing that. You will need to loop through the collections and test each value against every other value.

You may use a dictionary object or an array (or a spreadsheet) to hold the sets. You may use nested FOR - NEXT loops to loop through the sets.

VBA is a simple and powerful language. A prime reason people use R and python, in spite of their complexities and difficulties, is that VBA is very old language that does not include native methods of handling multi-dimensional sets.